Multi-level generic type conversion does not work as expected
I want to keep the key part of the original object when I pass typeof obj to the generic type, and return a converted value type.
As you see the below code example, the changed variable should not return error message since I used TryToCangeType type for the const variable.
As the logic of it, when it is { [key]: value } shape, it will call itself recursively, but when it is not the object shape, then it should simply return with wrapping of {value: [original type]}.
const obj = {
    _test1: 'hi',
    _test2: {
        test3: {
            _test4: {
                test5: 99,
            },
        },
    },
};

type TryToChangeType<K> = K extends {
    [Key2 in keyof K]: K[Key2];
typescript error message}   ? { [Key3 in keyof K]: TryToChangeType<K[Key3]> }
    : { [Key3 in keyof K]: { value: K[Key3]} };

const changed: TryToChangeType<typeof obj> = {
    _test1: { value: 'hi' },
    _test2: {
        test3: {
            _test4: {
                test5: { value: 99 },
            },
        },
    },
}

But it fails because instead of wrapping the original value, it does not wrap it.
error message
Does anyone recognize this issue?
In JavaScript logic, the above type returns properly.
Just a simple recursive logic. But in my library that I am trying to make, typescript support that shows all the original key-value structure is critical.
after converting the type, I want to access to

original type that is given
new structure that has different shape. (i.e. {value: number, init: boolean})


You can create an intersection type like this
type TryToChangeType<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [Key in keyof T as T[Key] extends Record<string, any> ? never : Key]: {
    value: T[Key];
  };
} & {
  [Key in keyof T as T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
    ? Key
    : never]: TryToChangeType<T[Key]>;
};

Which should give you the result you are looking for.
Here is a playground showing the example https://tsplay.dev/WyZOxw

this is a great solution! I did not know the syntax 'as'. looks solid! Thanks a lot!
